# TFS 2013 Plugin not firing

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to write a HelloWorld TFS plugin. I created a class library project. Code is here :

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TFSServerSideHandler
{
    public class WorkItemChangedEventHandler : ISubscriber
    {
        EventLog appLog = new EventLog();

        public string Name
        {
            get { return "WorkItemChangedEventHandler"; }
        }

        public SubscriberPriority Priority
        {
            get { return SubscriberPriority.High; }
        }

        public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(
            TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext,
            NotificationType notificationType,
            object notificationEventArgs,
            out int statusCode,
            out string statusMessage,
            out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
        {
            statusCode = 0;
            properties = null;
            statusMessage = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                appLog.Source = "WorkItemChangedEventHandler";
                appLog.WriteEntry("Handled event : " + notificationEventArgs.GetType().Name);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                appLog.Source = "WorkItemChangedEventHandler";
                appLog.WriteEntry("Couldn't Handle event : " + notificationEventArgs.GetType().Name + " Exception : " + exception.ToString());
            }
            return EventNotificationStatus.ActionPermitted;
        }

        public Type[] SubscribedTypes()
        {
            return new Type[] { typeof(WorkItemChangedEvent), typeof(CheckinNotification) };
        }
    }
}
```

I build the project and then deploy all files from \TFSServerSideHandler\bin\Debug to **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services\bin\Plugins** on my TFS server.

I'm using minimal installation of TFS 2013 with update 5 (12.0.40629.0 (Tfs2013.Update5)). 
I should see log entries when I do checkin code to this TFS server or when I change a work item, but I don't see any log entries from my code. Could anyone point me to what I'm missing here ?

References :
[image]

Comment: I also installed Visual Studio remote debugging tools on the TFS server. I tried to attach the visual studio debugger to w3p.exe on the TFS server, but break point never been hit we a checkin event happens.

Answer (score 0):

All logging should be done through the **TeamFoundationApplication class**, which has `“Log”` and `“LogException”` methods. This is important as it will use the TFS context to log information and use the same logging verbosity that is set for the TFS process.  **Avoid using `Applog.WriteEntry()` as your messages wouldn’t be logged as coming from TFS.**

The code:  This shows a sample implementation of code responding to a Check-in event:

```
namespace Sample.SourceControl.Server.PlugIns
{
    public class CodeCheckInEventHandler : ISubscriber
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get { return "CodeCheckInEventHandler"; }
        }

        public SubscriberPriority Priority
        {
            get { return SubscriberPriority.Normal; }
        }

        public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, NotificationType notificationType, object notificationEventArgs, out int statusCode, out string statusMessage, out Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
        {
            statusCode = 0;
            properties = null;
            statusMessage = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                if (notificationType == NotificationType.Notification && notificationEventArgs is WorkItemChangedEvent)
                {
                    CheckinNotification ev = notificationEventArgs as CheckinNotification;
                    TeamFoundationApplication.Log(string.Format("New Changeset was checked in by {0}. ID: {1}, comments: {2}", ev.ChangesetOwnerName, ev.Changeset, ev.Comment), 123, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TeamFoundationApplication.LogException("Sample.SourceControl.Server.PlugIns.CodeCheckInEventHandler encountered an exception", ex);
            }
            return EventNotificationStatus.ActionPermitted;
        }

        public Type[] SubscribedTypes()
        {
            return new Type[1] { typeof(CheckinNotification) };
        }
    }
}
```

More detailed info, please take a look at this blog: [TFS Server-side event handlers](http://www.almguide.com/2011/12/tfs-server-side-event-handlers/)